# Debugging kernel very early in boot process

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, arm, porting

I'm porting the Linux kernel to a new platform and I'm having a little trouble debugging.

The kernel seems to hang after `Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.` is printed to UART. I've enabled early printk but it still doesn't print anything new so I'm assuming it's hanging very early in the boot process.

The platform I'm porting to does have a LED I can use to try and pinpoint where it is actually hanging. The problem with this is that it's messy and I don't know when the MMU is going to be switched on so I can't reliably access the port.

Are there other ways to try and pinpoint where the kernel is hanging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMU is turned on in the kernel bootstrap ([head.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/head.S)), so just add some LED poking around there. See [this slightly outdated file](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/linux/ARM_Linux_boot_sequence.html) for overview of the boot sequence on ARM Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if the only real option here is a JTAG debug probe.   There are some relatively inexpensive devices on the market.

Not sure which family of SoC you're using, but if it's one TI,  [Code Composer Studio](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Download_CCS#Code_Composer_Studio_Version_5_Downloads) and 
 [XDS560](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/XDS560v2_System_Trace) system tracer might be worth a go.

The [Pandaboard community](http://www.pandaboard.org/content/debug-ti-pandaboard-jtag-using-busblaster-v2-and-openocd) is possibly also a good place to look - emphasis here being on low-cost solutions.

Whilst these are both TI focused, the probes often support different vendors' devices.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel do have an EARLY_PRINTK config. Enable this option will print debug messages before the standard console is started.

Notice this option depends on the DEBUG_LL option.

Comment: I mentioned in the original question that I had already enabled the early printk option.